# How do I select by month in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have a table of the form

```
t                             r             v    
-------------------------------------------------
2016.01.04D09:51:00.000000000 -0.01507338   576  
2016.01.04D09:52:00.000000000 -0.001831502  200  
2016.01.04D11:37:00.000000000 -0.001100514  583  
2016.01.04D12:04:00.000000000 -0.001653045  1000
```

I want to get the October 2020 values.

I tried doing a query:

```
select from x where t.month = 2020.10
```

but this didn't work. I think I might need to cast a date type? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing `m` allows the interpreter know that the atom is of month type instead of float type.

```
q)type 2020.10
-9h
q)type 2020.10m
-13h
q)select from x where t.month=2020.10
t
-
q)select from x where t.month=2020.10m
t
-----------------------------
2020.10.20D20:20:00.000000000
```